# Instancia ec2 se pasma al editar archivos js

Tags: javascript, vscode, aws

Tengo una instancia ec2 de aws lightsail a la que me conecto con VS code vía ssh, todo funcionaba bien hasta que empecé a hacer pruebas con los archivos .js, al guardar cualquier edición el servidor se muere y obtengo el UPSTREAM_NOT_FOUND [519] al intentar conectarme con ssh.
Encontré un artículo en aws que aconsejaba cambiar el servidor mediante un snapshot. Así lo hice, hasta cambié el tamaño del procesador, pero el problema sigue.

Comment: Podrías agregar un [ejemplo minimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) así  es mas probable elaborar una respuesta para tu pregunta.